# Facebook sample apps for Android not working

Tags: android, facebook

was just trying out the Facebook SDK for android followed the getting started guide. Completed all the steps, but when I imported the sample projects to eclipse, the compilation failed with the following error:

Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   ProfilePictureSampleFragment.java

I then added the supportLibrary (from AndroidSDK/extras/android/support/android-support-v4.jar)as an external jar. The compilation error was no longer there, but when I try to run the app, its throwing me this exception:

06-08 02:16:18.337: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 02:16:18.337: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.samples.profilepicture/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity

All other params are default. I am using a MAC OS and have registered the key hash to my developer settings. I am trying to run the ProfilePictureSample app.

Answer (score 1):

oh.. just got it working. Just went to Java build path and checked android-support-v4.jar in there. Worked :)